# SearchView not firing onQueryTextChange method to filter ListView

Tags: android

For some reason, my search view won't filter my list at all - it won't even enter the onQueryTextChange method. Here's my code

```
    public static class PokemonMoveTutorFragment extends Fragment implements SearchView.OnQueryTextListener {

    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public static PokemonMoveTutorFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PokemonMoveTutorFragment fragment = new PokemonMoveTutorFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PokemonMoveTutorFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_poke_details_tabs_moves, container, false);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.searchViewMoves);
        ListView l1=(ListView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pokeMoveList);
        TextView header = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.moveListHeader);
        header.setText("MOVES: TUTOR");
        ArrayList<Move> movesList = poke.getMoveset();
        ArrayList<Move> showMovesList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (Move move : movesList) {
            if (move.getLearnMethod() == 3) {
                showMovesList.add(move);
            }
        }

        Collections.sort(showMovesList, new Comparator() {
            public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
                Move p1 = (Move) o1;
                Move p2 = (Move) o2;
                return p1.getMoveName().compareTo(p2.getMoveName());
            }
        });

        moveListAdapter = new MoveListAdapter(con,showMovesList,false);
        l1.setAdapter(moveListAdapter);
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
        Log.i("SEARCHTEST","OnQueryTextChange: MoveList: " + newText);
        moveListAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

There are multiple uses of the same layout file for different fragments, none of which work.

In another activity I also search a list view (where the layout file is used for multiple fragments as well) that functions perfectly - but for some reason, even though both implementations are virtually identical, this will not work for me.

Any idea why? Thanks in advance

I can post the layout file code as well as the adapter code if you like, but since I can't even get onQueryTextChange to fire, I don't believe the problem is in there.

There are no errors or anything in the log to indicate why this is happening.

EDIT: Of course, immediately after posting I find something.
Somehow, it works in some of the fragments but not others, although it will work in the others if there is text already entered in the ones that function normally.  And it will enter the onQueryTextChange method for the ones that function normally.

So that's pretty confusing, I assume it's related to multiple fragments accessing the same layout file - any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well I fixed it, it was really a stupid mistake on my part :D

I used the same adapter for the ListView in every fragment, which was causing the problem.  A simple change to make the adapter local to each fragment fixed the issue.